# Loop ending after one iteration. Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to read a csv file of multiple rows, each delimited like this:
quote|source|dob-dod|wplink|wpimg|category

I want to check for rows that contain the category string 'romantic' and output that to a JSON.
I think I am nearly there but my loop stops after finding the first row with the relevant string. What am I missing to keep the loop going to find all relevant rows? Your help is very much appreciated!
Here is my code so far:

```
import csv,json
#create an empty dictionary
romantic = {}
with open('quotes.csv') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '|')
    
#filter using str: romantic
    for row in data:
        if row[5] == 'romantic':
                romantic['quotes'] = {
                'quote': row[0],
                'source': row[1],
                'dob-dod': row[2],
                'wplink' : row[3],
                'wpimg': row[4],
                'category':row[5]
                }
            
with open('romjson', 'w+') as jsonfile:
    jsonfile.write(json.dumps(romantic))

#print the json
print(romantic)
```

Comment: What makes you think it *stops*?

Comment: @Asquidbro's comment below helped me to see that the loop didn't stop but did overwrite the existing entry.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue that you rewrite `romantic['quotes']` every time you get `if row[5] == 'romantic':` condition, try this code instead (I've used list to store all quotes)

```
import csv,json
#create an empty dictionary
romantic = {'quotes': []}
with open('quotes.csv') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '|')
    
#filter using str: romantic
    for row in data:
        if row[5] == 'romantic':
                romantic['quotes'].append({
                'quote': row[0],
                'source': row[1],
                'dob-dod': row[2],
                'wplink' : row[3],
                'wpimg': row[4],
                'category':row[5]
                })
            
with open('romjson', 'w+') as jsonfile:
    jsonfile.write(json.dumps(romantic))

#print the json
print(romantic)
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I did figure I needed to append somewhere but wasn't sure where! I'm brand new to this and really appreciate the help! Thank you.